# How to encrypt / decrypt only certain amount of bytes (file)?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, partial

I'm implementing encryption/decryption of files, where only certain amount of bytes should be encrypted. 
**For example: I have 500 MB large file and I want to encrypt (and ofcourse decrypt) only 2 MB of file.**

I have implemented everything, Encryption works fine (without an error), but when I run Decryption it always throws out this error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.DepadBlock(Byte[] block, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at  System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
at ...
```

**Then I've tried to set the Padding** to `encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` (and also tried PaddingMode.Zeros, etc.). After running Encryption and Decryption with this Padding modes **the result of Decryption** is without error/exception, but encrypted part of a file is still encrypted, but a bit different. I've also checked that password is correct

Now I'dont have anymore solutions how to handle this "partial" encryption of files. Any ideas? How to deal with this padding or bytes?

**Here is my code of Encryption and Decryption process of certain amount of bytes (sorry for the length, but only that you will know :) ):**

```
static byte[] FILE_HEADER = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("header_of_file"); //this is written to the first line of encrypted file
static long limitBytes = 4096 * 8; //limit encryption to this amount of bytes

public static bool Encrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath, string EncryptionKey)
{
int bytesRead = 1;
long byteWriteCounter = 0;
long encryptedByteCounter = 0;
byte[] blength = null;
byte[] intBytes = null;
int bufferLen = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
blength = new byte[FILE_HEADER.Length];
long sumBytesRead = 0;

try
{
    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {                    
        fsInput.Read(blength, 0, blength.Length);

        if (!blength.SequenceEqual(FILE_HEADER)) //read the FILE_HEADER - if not equal that we can encrypt otherwise is already encrypted
        {
            fsInput.Position = 0;

            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {                            
                using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {

                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            while (bytesRead != 0)
                            {
                                bytesRead = fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
                                sumBytesRead += bytesRead;

                                if (sumBytesRead <= limitBytes) //limit encryption
                                {                                  

                                    if (bytesRead < bufferLen)
                                    {                                                   

                                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        encryptedByteCounter += bytesRead;
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;

                                        intBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(encryptedByteCounter.ToString("D7"));

                                        fsOutput.Position = 0;
                                        fsOutput.Write(FILE_HEADER, 0, FILE_HEADER.Length); //we write our header to file, to know which is encrypted
                                        fsOutput.Write(intBytes, 0, intBytes.Length); //we write number of encrypted bytes next to header, for decryption to know
                                        bytesRead = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        encryptedByteCounter += bytesRead;
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;

                                    }
                                }
                                else //if the file is bigger than limit, we continue to write normal data (unencrypted)
                                {
                                    if (bytesRead < bufferLen)
                                    {
                                        fsOutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;
                                        intBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(encryptedByteCounter.ToString("D7"));

                                        fsOutput.Position = 0;
                                        fsOutput.Write(FILE_HEADER, 0, FILE_HEADER.Length);
                                        fsOutput.Write(intBytes, 0, intBytes.Length);
                                        bytesRead = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        fsOutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }
                        catch (SystemException se)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Exception ENC: " + se);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            //file is already encrypted
            return false;
        }
    }


}
catch (SystemException se)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Main ENC exception: "+se);

    return false;
}

}
```

**... and Decryption function:**

```
public static bool Decrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath, string EncryptionKey)
{
byte[] blength = null;
blength = new byte[FILE_HEADER.Length];
long byteWriteCounter = 0;
int bufferLen = 4096; 
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
int bytesRead = 1;
long decryptedByteCounter = 0;
long sumBytesRead = 0;
byte[] bufferEncBytes = new byte[7];

try
{

    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {

        fsInput.Read(blength, 0, blength.Length);

        if (blength.SequenceEqual(FILE_HEADER))//check if is our encrypted file
        {


            fsInput.Read(bufferEncBytes, 0, bufferEncBytes.Length);

            int numOfDecBytes = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.Default.GetString(bufferEncBytes)); //get number of encrypted bytes

            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {                   
                using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);                        

                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            while (bytesRead != 0)
                            {
                                bytesRead = fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
                                sumBytesRead += bytesRead;

                                if (sumBytesRead <= numOfDecBytes) //decrypt until limit
                                {

                                    if (bytesRead < bufferLen)
                                    {
                                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        decryptedByteCounter += bytesRead;
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;

                                        bytesRead = 0; //we are at the end of file, end everything
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        decryptedByteCounter += bytesRead;
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;                                         
                                    }
                                }
                                else //if we have decrypted encrypted bytes, continue with rest of the (normal) data
                                {
                                    if (bytesRead < bufferLen)
                                    {
                                        fsOutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;

                                        bytesRead = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        fsOutput.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        byteWriteCounter += bytesRead;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }
                        catch (SystemException se)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Exception DECR: " + se);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //not right file for decryption
            return false;
        }
    }

}
catch (SystemException eks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + eks); //here the exception of Invalid Padding is thrown

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: This basically amounts to debugging the file handling.  The assumption that your ciphertext is as large as the plain text is wrong. The assumption that you read exactly to the end of the plaintext you want to encrypt seems wrong as well. Ciphertext may also be larger than the plaintext. All in all many errors, and encrypt/decrypt methods that try to do everything instead of making a good design.

Comment: Why do you only want to encrypt part of the file? That's clearly not secure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead I know, that there are many errors, I'm in developing phase testing if it works with my logic. But can you help and provide solution how to achieve amount of encrypted bytes, that in Decryption can be counted and decrypted? Or should I use other Encryption algorithm?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I didn't find any other solution to encrypt a lot of 2GB+ (.iso) files faster. If you encrypt small piece of such big files, the overall result is the same - file can not be used..

Comment: @OnlyKing For DRM that might be acceptable (it's broken anyways), for anything security related it's not. A competent attacker will be able to extract most files from that iso file if you only encrypt the beginning. But even for DRM it makes little sense, since you only need on the fly decryption where you're limited by IO performance, not CPU cost of decryption.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Agree, but as you said, I'm limited by IO performance...

Comment: @OnlyKing That's a pretty weird usecase. Why are you storing a plaintext file in the first place, if you plan to replace it by an encrypted file? Encrypting individual files only makes sense if you transfer them elsewhere, at which point you need to do the IO anyways.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Where do you see that I store a plaintext file? inputFile is any (format) file, which is readed by bytes and written as encrypted file..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt / decrypt only first few bytes of a file (the rest should be unencrypted)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925571/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-only-first-few-bytes-of-a-file-the-rest-should-be-unen)  (i.e. the question you already posted three days ago and for which you received an answer. why are you posting essentially same question again?)

Answer (score 2):

When you encrypt with a block cypher, most modes will add padding.  That means that the encrypted data will be *longer* that the original plaintext, because of the extra padding.  You need to keep the padding with the encrypted data, otherwise you will get the bad padding error.

You can either make sure that you handle the padding carefully, or switch to CTR mode, which does not use padding, giving a cyphertext the same length as the plaintext.

Using a Stream Cypher, like Rabbit or Salsa20 would have the same effect.

Comment: And how can I handle Padding carefully in this case? This algorithm does not support CTR mode..

Comment: If you store the plaintext size in front of the ciphertext then you could try and implement padding up to the block size (i.e. 0..15 bytes for AES). In that case make sure your buffer and amount of bytes to encrypt are both multiples of the block size. Then you could use `NoPadding` to encrypt/decrypt the required bytes. In case you already encrypt to the maximum then you would not need to pad. In the other case you could pad by just filling the last part of the buffer with zeros. PS in your case I certainly would consider storing 64 bits for the size of plaintext.

Comment: Encrypt, and record the size of the *encrypted* bytes.  Prepend those bytes to the front of the unencrypted portion of your file.  Keep a fixed size record of the cyphertext size which you prepend to the cyphertext.  On the decryption end, first read the cyphertext size.  Then decrypt exactly that many bytes (the padding should automatically disappear).  Prepend the decrypted plaintext to the unencrypted remainder of the file.  Make sure the fixed size length variable is large enough to hold the longest possible cyphertext size you will need.